# Reading HttpRequest sent by Java in PHP

Tags: java, php, httpwebrequest

```
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://abc.com/a.php");
postMethod.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(new ByteArrayInputStream(someString.getBytes())));
HttpClient httpClient = initMultithreadedHttpClient(ConnectionTimeout,
                SocketTimeout, MaxRetry);
httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

This is how I am sending data from Java client to PHP server.
**How do I read it in PHP?**

I tried to capture the data like this:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("/opt/lampp/htdocs/input.txt","w");
ob_start();
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_SERVER);
print_r(http_get_request_body());
fprintf($fp,"%s",ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
fclose($fp);
?>
```

But it didn't really print the request data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read raw POST data in PHP with...

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I prefer this method over the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` global.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function instead of `http_get_request_body`:

```
function get_post_body() {
  $body = '';
  $fh   = @fopen('php://input', 'r');
  if ($fh)
  {
    while (!feof($fh))
    {
      $s = fread($fh, 1024);
      if (is_string($s))
      {
        $body .= $s;
      }
    }
    fclose($fh);
  } 
  return $body
}
```